# Переменная var undefined если ее обьявлять через windows.userName почему?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<script>
        // ailabs_user_info  = {'user_intent_category_label':'DEFAULT', 'info_fullname':'fiotesttest', 'info_iin':'test', 'info_phone_number':'test'};
        setTimeout(function(){
            var ailabs_user_info = window.userName;
            console.log('3 sek');
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(ailabs_user_info);
                AILabsChatStart();
            }, 2000);
        }, 3000);
    </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переменная var не найдена если ее обьявлять через windows.userName вызывая обьект путем get методов для получения данных каждого пользователя отдельно.
Но если раскоментить строку первую кода то он ее видит но мне нужны данные которые в реакте тяну методом get а не эти тестовые. Почему он не видит

```
var ailabs_user_info = window.userName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что эта переменная - локальная, объявленная внутри функции-обработчика таймера. Она не видна внутри функции `AILabsChatStart`.

```
    var ailabs_user_info;
    setTimeout(function(){
        ailabs_user_info = window.userName;
        console.log('3 sek');
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(ailabs_user_info);
            AILabsChatStart();
        }, 2000);
    }, 3000);
```